# Junit Assert for If statement

Tags: java, junit

What the reasonable Assert in Junit to use it for if statement which has multiple conditions? For example if ( grade > 10 && grade < 100)

Comment: What's wrong with that exact expression?

Comment: i mean like assertEquals, assertTrue, etc

Comment: `assertTrue(grade > 10 && grade < 100)`

Answer (score 2):

Computer programs should be *deterministic*. That is: a *distinct set* of input values always results in the *same* output value(s).

Therefore a unittest (method) should verify a (single) *distinct outcome* according to *distinct inputs*. Therefore you (usually) assert a single well known value and not a range.

If your program is not deterministic (maybe because of the use of *randomness* or some hard to control *state*) you should replace this dependencies introducing the non deterministic by *test doubles* (stubs, fakes or mocks).